# Search results page shows all results on first page

Tags: magento-1.7, catalogsearch, search

My category grid works fine, page 1 shows products 1-100, page 2 shows 101-200 and so on.

However, on the search results page, all results are listed on the first page, so page 1 shows results 1-289 for example. And the pager information next to the number of pages says "PRODUCTS 1 TO 289 OF 289". The number of pages is calculated and displayed correctly.

When I investigate the collection I can see that something's wrong:

```
echo $collection->getPageSize(); // 100
echo $collection->getCurPage(); // 1
echo $collection->count(); // 138 -> This should also be set to 100, as the current page is 1 and the page size is 100..
```

And looking at the query for the collection, I see that it's missing the `LIMIT 100` right at the end of the query.

Does anybody know what could be causing this?

Comment: did you install any extension that could overwrite the search layered navigation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not 100% sure what caused this odd behavior, but I solved it by defining a pager limit for the search result page by adding this into my theme's *local.xml*:

```
<catalogsearch_result_index>
    <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>20</limit></action>
        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>20</limit></action>
    </reference>
</catalogsearch_result_index>
```